# Please notify voters if a nomination is withdrawn during the election phase

Tags: discussion, election, nominations

I did recast my votes in an election due to a withdrawn nomination. Thanks to my luck, I didn't waste any of 3 votes. Hopefully no more nominations will be withdrawn without notice.

> **Nomination withdrawn at candidate's request.**
>
> Votes for this candidate will be reallocated according to the Meek STV
> algorithm.
>
> You can recast your existing votes at any time until the election ends

It's possible that all candidates I voted may withdraw. In this case, the STV doesn't help at all and I completely miss the election. It would be nice to receive notifications for withdrawals.

Comment: I may hope this was a one-of situation. I expect it to be non-trivial and I rather have dev-time spend on other stuff, say new user on-boarding or the mod-tools.

Comment: The post saying goodbye from the withdrawing candidate was featured to try and reach as many voters as possible, but I’d very much welcome a notification for those that voted already. That said, the withdrawal was early and this kind of thing should be extremely rare.

Answer (score 20):

As far as I can tell, this is the first time a candidate withdrew during the election phase. Hopefully, it will be the last, and this is not worth spending valuable development time on. It takes rather severe circumstances for this to happen, let's hope we're spared from such in the future.